# Java semaphore to syncronize printing to screen

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently stuck on a bit of homework and was wondering if anyone could help -

I have to use semaphores in java to synchronize printing letters from 2 threads - one printing "A" and one printing "B". I cannot print out more than 2 of the same character in a row, so output should look like

> AABABABABABBABABABABAABBAABBABABA

At the moment I have 3 semaphores, a binary mutex set to 1, and a counting semaphore, and my thread classes look something like this -

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Time.delay(RandomGenerator.integer(0,20));
        Semaphores.mutex.down ();
        System.out.println (produce());

          if (printCount > 1)
          { printCount = 0;
                Semaphores.mutex.up ();
                Semaphores.printB.up();
          }
    } 
}
public String produce() {
    printCount++;
    return "A";
}


public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Time.delay(RandomGenerator.integer(0,20));
        Semaphores.mutex.down ();
        System.out.println (produce());

          if (printCount > 1)
          { printCount = 0;
                Semaphores.mutex.up ();
                Semaphores.printA.up();
          }
    } 
}
public String produce() {
    printCount++;
    return "B";
}
```

Yet whatever I try it either deadlocks, or it seems to be working only printing 2 in a row at most, but always seems to print 3 in a row every now and again!

Any help is much appreciated, not looking code or anything just a few pointers if possible :)

Comment: Although this is off the requirement, you can use Peterson algorithm for this.

Comment: won't the if condition always be true?

Comment: Once printCount is greater than 1, I reset it back to 0 so it can start over again, in the produce () method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be setting the printA and printB semaphores up without ever setting them down.  If they are attempted to be set up multiple times, they would be waiting on themselves.

---

To answer the comment of "Where would I set them down?"

I am not quite sure, to be honest.  The only thing I could imagine is if the professor is trying to exploit the fact that (in java) you can release a semaphore more times than originally acquired.

If so, then the pattern would be two semaphores, one  for producer 'B' and one for producer 'B'.  Each of their produce methods would Acquire on their own semaphore and release on the opposing producer's semaphore.  The semaphore count would therefore be the number of times the producer acquired without a corresponding release from the other producer, but this method is at odds with the conceptual intent of a Semaphore, depends upon Java specifc implementation and just outright makes me queasy.

I would sooner implement this using a third Manager or Consumer thread that does the throttling or by using Interlocked operations on a shared integer.  Either way, not using a semaphore.  Semaphores would be useful if we wanted to ensure that only three short lived producers were executing autonomously

Comment: Where would I call down? I have

Semaphores.mutex.down();
            System.out.println(produce());
            if (printCount > 1)
            {
                printCount = 0;
                Semaphores.mutex.up();
                Semaphores.printB.up();
                Semaphores.printA.down ();
            }
            Semaphores.mutex.up();

But it still manages to print out 3 in a row sometimes for some reason